# Why do I need os.environ in my pyspark program?

Tags: python, pyspark, environment-variables, conda

I built a simple program to test my first setup of an apache-spark environment using pyspark and got an error that seems to be very common on StackOverflow: `Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.7.`

I found several fixes and the only one that worked for me was adding the following line within the script: `os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"]="/Users/username/Library/miniconda3/envs/env_name/bin/python"`

I have the variables set in BOTH `~/.zshrc` AND in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`:

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/Users/username/Library/miniconda3/envs/env_name/bin/python
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/Users/username/Library/miniconda3/envs/env_name/bin/python
```

All the environment variables point to the same python 3.7 path that the simple program is using. If I run `pyspark` from the command line, it also specifies 3.7. Again, it's working with `os.environ`, but my question is WHY does it need that if I've configured my drivers and workers to 3.7? Where was the worker's 2.7 version coming from (before I was specifying the `os.environ` in the script)?

(I'm building the code in Sublime Text on macOS Catalina. The environment variables are pointing to and my code is running in a conda environment running on python 3.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any user defined environment variables you need **os.environ** to be included in your code. When you export the variable, it will be applicable only for that session and code fail in case its executed some time later. **os.environ** manages these kind of issue ensuring that to direct to user defined environment variables.